White fungus at the tree base leading to leaf loss
I am located in Adelaide, SA, and have noticed a significant issue with the trees on my street, including my own. Many of the trees are exhibiting white fungal or mushroom-like growths at their bases and on the surrounding lawns. These trees are now completely defoliated and appear to be dying.
Despite attempts to remove the fungus in the past, it has reappeared, growing more extensively and aggressively. If anyone has insights into what this fungus might be and effective methods for controlling or eliminating it, your advice would be greatly appreciated.




As with many other fungi, by the time the visible part (fruiting body - the white fungus you see) has appeared, the fungal colony has been long established in a much larger volume of the tree out of your sight. Removing what you see is of little more significance to the fungal colony in the tree than trimming your fingernails is to you.

I know this fungus as one of the shelf fungi.  The link indicates

Once a tree is infected, the fungus cannot be killed.

There are many different types of shelf fungus and their actions differ from tree species to species.
My suspicion is that this tree is dying and at the very least is unsafe to have near any cars or houses as it could shed branches in windstorms.
The best way to verify this is to get an arborist in as they will be aware of the local conditions.
